# Postman showing HTML instead of JSON

Tags: java, spring-security, postman

I have a simple Spring Boot + Spring Security REST app with quotations. Only 3 endpoints for GET, POST, DELETE. Only moderator and admin accounts defined. GET rest method works fine - it shows list of quotations. The problem is with POST and DELETE methods. When I try to invoke them in Postman it returns HTML (logging form defined in SecurityConfig).

**QuotationApi.java**

```java
@RestController
public class QuotationApi {

    private List<Quotation> quotations;

    public QuotationApi() {
        this.quotations = new ArrayList<>();
        quotations.add(new Quotation("Those who dare to fail miserably can achieve greatly.", "John F. Kennedy"));
        quotations.add(new Quotation("Get busy living or get busy dying.", "Stephen King"));
    }

    @GetMapping("/api")
    public List<Quotation> getQuotation() {
        return quotations;
    }

    @PostMapping("/api")
    public boolean addQuotation(@RequestBody Quotation quotation) {
        return quotations.add(quotation);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/api")
    public void deleteQuotation(@RequestParam int index) {
        quotations.remove(index);
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // creating users
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        UserDetails moderator = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("user")
                .roles("MODERATOR")
                .build();

        UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(moderator, admin);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api").hasRole("MODERATOR")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/api").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

I have Basic_auth in Postman:
[image]

EDIT after Andreas's help (working code):

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api").hasRole("MODERATOR")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/api").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't matter that Postman is sending Basic authentication header, when you haven't enabled Basic authentication in Spring.

Since you only called [`formLogin()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#formLogin--) to enable form based authentication, you have to login using the form `POST`.

Of course, you could just call [`httpBasic()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#httpBasic--) to enable Basic authentication too.